# Need to join 3 collection for mongodb to find the aggregated data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My knowledge in mongodb is little. I have store list as store collection which has only store basic details

```
Store collection:
[
  {
    "id": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "name": "Chad store",
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab",
    "name": "Bad store",
  }
]
```

I have signal-records collection which has the multiple signals records for each store.
signal records are like no. of signal bars, signal strength etc
Few stores may not have signal records.

```
Signal records:

[
  {
    "id": "5dc250e0d972e71c3b3e6e88",
    "signalStrength": -180,
    "signalbars": "3",
    "employee": "5db59227f0204855654075ee",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87"
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc251f723760a24de167f8e",
    "signalStrength": -180,
    "signalbars": "3",
    "employee": "5db59227f0204855654075ee",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87"
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc289affd1ea02f0fceb9ac",
    "signalStrength": -80,
    "signalbars": "3",
    "employee": "5db59227f0204855654075ee",
    "store": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab"
  }
]
```

then there is another collection called speed tests  for each stores similar to signal-records with fields like 
upload/download speed.

```
Speed Tests:

[
  {
    "id": "5dc2c170e26c4a484051f4af",
    "ping": 10,
    "downloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "uploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "employee": "5dc2b9467a56f3446dcaf8f6",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87"
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc3a0a92588214e1a938a34",
    "ping": 10,
    "downloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "uploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "employee": "5dc2b9467a56f3446dcaf8f6",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87"
  }
]
```

Now i do need to find the store list along with number of signal records(if no records then its should be 0) and 
average of those signals strength, avg of signal bars, average upload/download speed etc.

```
Expected output:

[
  {
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "storeName": "Chad store",
    "averageSignalStrength": -180,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 7.66
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 4.22
    "totalSpeedTests": 2
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 1
  },
  {
    "store": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab",
    "storeName": "Bad store",
    "averageSignalStrength": -80,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 0
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 0
    "totalSpeedTests": 0
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 0
  }
]
```

I have used this inside aggregator keeping store as parent with minimum requirement to test. The problem i faced here 
if no speed tests are available for the store them those stores are not taken into consideration 
when you do group by.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following aggregations.

$lookup to join signals and speedTests.

$project to construct calculated fields.

$ifNull to handle null averages as 0.

$setDifference to count distinct values.

Here is the aggregation you need:

```
db.store.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "signals",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "store",
      as: "storeSignals"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "speedTests",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "store",
      as: "speedTests"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      store: "$id",
      storeName: "$name",
      averageSignalStrength: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $avg: "$storeSignals.signalStrength"
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      averageUploadSpeed: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $avg: "$speedTests.uploadSpeed"
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      averageDownloadSpeed: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $avg: "$speedTests.downloadSpeed"
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      totalSpeedTests: {
        $size: "$speedTests"
      },
      totalSpeedtestTesters: {
        "$size": {
          "$setDifference": [
            "$speedTests.employee",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "averageSignalStrength": -180,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "storeName": "Chad store",
    "totalSpeedTests": 2,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 1
  },
  {
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 0,
    "averageSignalStrength": -80,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 0,
    "store": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab",
    "storeName": "Bad store",
    "totalSpeedTests": 0,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 0
  }
]
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/MwJ26hAx996

Comment: @Prajwal you are welcome, please mark as asnwer to show that your question is resolved.

Comment: I have marked it :) @SuleymanSah: can you help me with this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746035/need-to-join-2-collection-for-mongodb-to-find-the-aggregated-data-based-on-colle

Comment: @Prajwal thank you, I will look at, and if I can solve, will  post an answer.

Comment: @Prajwal I added an answer to your new question, can you check? Also you need to edit your new question to add your Speed Tests collection data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup`. 
Getting totalSpeedtestTesters value in MongoDB a little bit hard. I guess you need unique value. I recommend to make it on client-side

```
db.getCollection('Store').aggregate([
    {$lookup:
           {
             from: "Signal",
             localField: "id",
             foreignField: "store" ,
             as: "signals"
           }
    }
    ,{$lookup:
           {
             from: "Speed",
             localField: "id",
             foreignField: "store" ,
             as: "speeds"
           }
    }
    ,{$project :{ 
        store: "$id", 
        storeName: "$name",
        averageSignalStrength:  {
          $avg: "$signals.signalStrength"
        }
        ,averageUploadSpeed: {
          $avg: "$speeds.uploadSpeed"
        }
        ,averageDownloadSpeed:{
          $avg: "$speeds.downloadSpeed"
        }
        ,totalSpeedTests : {
          $size: "$speeds"
        }
        ,totalSpeedtestTesters:"$speeds.employee"
        }
     }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i get `totalSpeedTests` always one though there were no records. I think that is because the lookup will have at least 1 record in its output. It looks good when actually there is 1 or more speed test documents. Any idea?

Comment: i also tested it and in `totalSpeedTests` i got `0` as resutl. see this mongoplayaround. https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Fj_ijRUgKm

Comment: and, one important thing in aggregate pipeline stages is that your data types need to be defined properly. check in your `signalbar` field of signal records. data type is string of `signalbar` field. In this case some of operator ignores value of string because of string field.

Comment: count worked fine but totalSpeedtestTesters count is not correct here