# Need to join 2 collection for mongodb to find the aggregated data based on collection field

Tags: mongodb

I have store list as store collection which has only store basic details

```js
Store collection:
[
  {
    "id": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "name": "Chad store",
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab",
    "name": "Bad store",
  }
]
```

I have signal-records collection which has the multiple signals records for each store.
signal records are like no. of signal bars, signal strength etc Few stores may not have signal records.

```js
 Signal records:

[
  {
    "id": "5dc250e0d972e71c3b3e6e88",
    "signalStrength": -180,
    "signalbars": "3",
    "employee": "5db59227f0204855654075ee",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "carrierName": "LT&T"
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc251f723760a24de167f8e",
    "signalStrength": -180,
    "signalbars": "3",
    "employee": "5db59227f0204855654075ee",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "carrierName": "Sprint"
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc289affd1ea02f0fceb9ac",
    "signalStrength": -80,
    "signalbars": "3",
    "employee": "5db59227f0204855654075ee",
    "store": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab",
    "carrierName": "LT&T"
  }
]
```

```js
Speed Tests:

[
  {
    "id": "5dc2c170e26c4a484051f4af",
    "carrierName": "Sprint"
    "ping": 10,
    "downloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "uploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "employee": "5dc2b9467a56f3446dcaf8f6",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87"
  },
  {
    "id": "5dc3a0a92588214e1a938a34",
    "carrierName": "LT&T",
    "ping": 10,
    "downloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "uploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "employee": "5dc2b9467a56f3446dcaf8f6",
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87"
  }
]
```

I need to list stores and its signal strength based on its carrier names.

Expected output:

```js
Expected output:

[
  {
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "storeName": "Chad store",
    "carrierName": "LT&T",
    "averageSignalStrength": -180,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 7.66,
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 4.22,
    "totalSpeedTests": 2,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 1
  },
  {
    "store": "5dc25092d972e71c3b3e6e87",
    "storeName": "Chad store",
    "carrierName": "Sprint",
    "averageSignalStrength": -180,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 7.66,
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 4.22,
    "totalSpeedTests": 2,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 1
  },
  {
    "store": "5dc2899bfd1ea02f0fceb9ab",
    "storeName": "Bad store",
    "carrierName": "LT&T",
    "averageSignalStrength": -80,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 0,
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 0,
    "totalSpeedTests": 0,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 0
  }
]
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: You need to include Speed Tests collection which you mentioned in one of your other questions.

Comment: @SuleymanSah i have updated the collection. Please note that there is carrier name in speed tests too. 
your current answer works fine except if same store has multiple records for same carrier name then that store gets repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following aggregations.

$lookup to join signals and speedTests.

$unwind to deconstruct storeSignals array field.

$replaceRoot and $mergeRoot to shape the output you wanted.

$ifNull to handle null averages as 0.

$setDifference to count distinct values.

You can use the following aggregation:

```
db.store.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "signals",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "store",
      as: "storeSignals"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "speedTests",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "store",
      as: "speedTests"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$storeSignals",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$storeSignals",
          {
            "store": "$_id",
            "storeName": "$name",
            "carrierName": "$carrierName",
            "speedTests": "$speedTests",
            "signalStrength": "$signalStrength",

          },

        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      store: "$store",
      storeName: "$storeName",
      carrierName: "$carrierName",
      averageSignalStrength: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $avg: "$signalStrength"
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      averageUploadSpeed: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $avg: "$speedTests.uploadSpeed"
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      averageDownloadSpeed: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $avg: "$speedTests.downloadSpeed"
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      totalSpeedTests: {
        $size: "$speedTests"
      },
      totalSpeedtestTesters: {
        "$size": {
          "$setDifference": [
            "$speedTests.employee",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

])
```

Output will be like this:

```
[
  {
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "averageSignalStrength": -180,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "carrierName": "LT\u0026T",
    "store": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "storeName": "Chad store",
    "totalSpeedTests": 2,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 1
  },
  {
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 7.66,
    "averageSignalStrength": -180,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 4.22,
    "carrierName": "Sprint",
    "store": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "storeName": "Chad store",
    "totalSpeedTests": 2,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 1
  },
  {
    "averageDownloadSpeed": 0,
    "averageSignalStrength": -80,
    "averageUploadSpeed": 0,
    "carrierName": "LT\u0026T",
    "store": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000006"),
    "storeName": "Bad store",
    "totalSpeedTests": 0,
    "totalSpeedtestTesters": 0
  }
]
```

Playground to test if it is working:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/WTDPKEKGS1F

Comment: just verified the query. looks great but have one issue. if a signals record has same network carriers  then that store is repeating in the response.

Comment: @Prajwal is it normal that same signals in data?

Comment: @Prajwal ok but is it normal that duplicate signals exist in input documents?

Comment: we do not want to show the aggregated value for same store and carrier actually. i think thats still ok for me to continue. Thanks for the help :) I have updated the speed test collection here. Can we apply same concept there too? we have carrier name in speed test records?

Comment: @Prajwal maybe you can try first. I will try to remove duplicate signals in output,  but I think it would be better to not to have duplicate signals in input.

Comment: we are capturing time interval based signals, So there are chances we could get same signal records in different intervals.

Comment: @Prajwal   what is the rule for duplicate signals?

Comment: Signal records are captured every 15 mins with the carrier name. rest of details may or may not remain same. but recorded time will be different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202004/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-prajwal).

Comment: As per the question the answer worked like champ.. Thanks @SuleymanSah

Comment: @Prajwal  you are right, have a look at this please: https://mongoplayground.net/p/D8uywbaxNwH

Comment: if we do not have signal records but we have speed test records, The query return empty documents. can we list those stores who at least have one speed test or signal records?

Comment: @Prajwal  have a look at this please: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qkClbKy_1np   I added preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true to the unwind stage.

Comment: Thanks @SuleymanSah after this change carrier name is trimmed out. Thats because we fetch signal records which is empty now. In such case shall we take from speed tests(even speed test has carrier name).